# Is it possible to reference an excel cell in a comment?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel balance sheet with a total at the bottom. On that cell I have a comment that says that the reason the total is X is because of what happens in J2. What happens if I insert another row before that, now my comment is wrong because all the rows jumped up a value.

Is there any way to reference a cell dynamically in an Excel commment?

Comment: You could insert a name for J2 and refer to the cell by its name in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would say: not without VBA, except for using Named-Cells, like Jüri suggested.

As far as I know, comments are not designed to be interpreted like that. This would be quite an additional feature, so I bet MS would have told you about it in their help.

However, you can do some workarounds, like using Named ranges, or editing your comment through VBA - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567167/excel-how-to-return-comment-as-a-cell-from-a-conditional/12567739#12567739

Another workaround might be, to use comments inside your formula, like this:

```
=SUM(A:A)+N("Summed up my values according to" & J12)
```

`J12` would be changed to J11 or K12, when cells are removed or inserted.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to reference `named range` in Excel comment? Can you make it a hyperlink, that when clicked on that, would take me to that cell?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can rename the cell itself. You can simply type a name over where it says J12 to the left of the insert function button. Then you can refer to it by name in your comment. If the cell moves, its name remains with it.